# Fast way to search in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a php script which takes two csv files as input and each contains rows more than 40000, after uploading both files i convert them as array. Now i have two multidimensional arrays having 40000+ elements. like this

```
$file1 = array(
    array('name'=>'A','count'=>10),
    array('name'=>'B','count'=>13),
    array('name'=>'C','count'=>15),
    array('name'=>'D','count'=>12),
    array('name'=>'E','count'=>19),
);

$file2 = array(
    array('name'=>'A','count'=>34),
    array('name'=>'B','count'=>15),
    array('name'=>'C','count'=>43),
    array('name'=>'D','count'=>65),
    array('name'=>'E','count'=>98),
);
```

Now, I loop through first file array and find the same element in file two array

```
$output = array();

foreach($file1 as $element)
{
    $file1_count = find_element($element['name']);
    $count = $element['count']/(1+$file1_count);
    $output[] = array('name'=>$element['name'],'count'=>$count);
}

function find_element($element)
{
    foreach($this->control_group as $_element) {
        if($_element['name'] === $element)
            return $_element['count'];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is taking too much time, how can i make it run faster ?

Would it be better if i store first file to database and then make comparisons ?

Comment: If your array is always 'name' and 'count', you re simply loading it wrong. Make each $file array have the 'name' value as the key and the 'count' value as the value. Then, you can see if something like 'D' is set in either one by using the isset command. No looping necessary.

Comment: @kainaw yes, that is exactly what I thought. And he may use `array_key_exists` or `in_array` instead of looping

Comment: I considered that but this trick does not work for me because i have special symbols in names too.

Comment: then you can maybe `md5` your name and use it as key and comparer

Comment: @steven md5 won't contain special characters ? means whatever is generated by md5 will be acceptable by array key rules ?

Comment: @RohitKhatri Yes. MD5 will create a string using 0-9 and a-f - all valid characters. Then, to see if 'D' is set, you use if(isset($file2[md5('D'))).....

Comment: `md5($name)` should create a valid key in any case but it is not collision resistent. that means you have to check if some other name produces the same key.

Comment: @MariM is `crc32` sounds nice, is it collision resistent?

Comment: I deleted my comment because I wasn't thinking haha. `crc32` is not collision resistant at all.

Comment: Okay how about this? When saving the array, use the hash of the key to represent an array. If there is a collision, just store another value into that array. Then when you check, if the key exists, get the count of the array. If it's 1 then there's your match. If more than 1, explicitly check the strings for which one matches. Then it doesn't matter if you use `md5` or `crc32`

Comment: @steven What should i use for collision resistant ?

Comment: @steven can you provide an example ?

Comment: i think no hash method is really collision resistant because it converts a string of length N to a shorter string of a fixed lenght. But you may use it if you check if the resulting hash already exists while creating the hashes.

Comment: @RohitKhatri are your values for field `name` unique in each array?

Comment: @steven if i check whether md5 hash already exists, or not if exists i simply create another hash for that element but in that case how will i match that with isset method ?

Comment: @steven yes they are unique.

Comment: @RohitKhatri yes, that is a problem. You need to store a mapping array which maps the hash-value to the name: `array( array($hash => $name), array($hash => $name),... )` to be able to find the used hash for a given name..

Comment: @steven please, can you give me a practical example ?

Comment: You say "It is taking too much time."  How much time is it taking, and how much time would you like it to take?

Comment: @AndyLester It was taking more than 3 hours. I wanted to complete it in 5 minutes max.

Comment: If you wanted to use the 'hash' of the 'name; as an array key. I would use one of the 'cryptographic' hashes such as 'sha256' which are unlikely to have collisions. You can check the values for collisions when creating the 'lookup' array anyway.

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent but i used md5 and it worked great. No problem until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this function to get first file as md5

```
$control_group = csv_to_array($control_group,$header,true);
$group = csv_to_array($group,$header);

function csv_to_array($file,$header,$md5=false)
{
    $csv = array();

    if(($file = fopen($file, 'r')) === false)
        throw new Exception('There was an error loading the CSV file.');
    else
    {
        fgets($file);

        if($md5) {
            while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000)) !== false)
                $csv[md5($line[0])] = $line[1];
        } else {
            while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000)) !== false)
                $csv[] = array('name'=>$line[0],'count'=>$line[1]);
        }

        fclose($file);
    }

    return $csv;
}
```

and this function for comparison

```
function process($control_group,$group)
{
    $output = array();

    foreach($group as $element)
    {
        $control_group_frequency = isset($control_group[md5($element['name'])]) ? $control_group[md5($element['name'])] : 0;
        $frequency = round($element['count']/(1+$control_group_frequency),2);
        $output[] = array($element['name'],$element['count'],$frequency);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

and it worked great for me.

Thanks to @steven

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't go to sleep without trying to solve it.

I did it without hashing the name now. Because of the collision problem and the uniqueness of the name field I used a simple integer index as main key.

I don't really know how fast it is. I had to use `array_keys` to find the index for the given name and i think this is the bottleneck. If you are 100% shure that the names in `$file1` are exactly the same like in `$file2` (same names at same position in array) you can replace the `array_keys` stuff and take the index in current array instead. (i hope you know what i mean)

```
 $file1 = array(
    array('name'=>'A','count'=>10),
    array('name'=>'B','count'=>13),
    array('name'=>'C','count'=>15),
    array('name'=>'D','count'=>12),
    array('name'=>'E','count'=>19),
);

$file2 = array(
    array('name'=>'A','count'=>34),
    array('name'=>'B','count'=>15),
    array('name'=>'C','count'=>43),
    array('name'=>'D','count'=>65),
    array('name'=>'E','count'=>98),
);

$executer = new executer();
$executer->init($file2);
$out = $executer->work($file1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
echo "</pre>"; 

class executer {

    private $name_map = array();

    private $count_map = array();

    private $output = array();

    function init($base_array) {        
        $idx = 0;
        foreach($base_array as $a) {
            $this->name_map[$idx] = $a['name'];
            $this->count_map[$idx] = $a['count'];
            $idx++;
        }
    }

    function work($compare_array) {
        foreach($compare_array as $c) {

            if(!in_array($c['name'], $this->name_map)) {
                continue;
            }

            $keys = array_keys($this->name_map, $c['name']);            
            if(count($keys) !== 1) {
                throw new Exception("This should not happen");
            }

            $idx = $keys[0];

            $file1_count = $this->count_map[$idx];
            $count = $c['count']/(1+$file1_count);
            $this->output[] =  array('name'=>$this->name_map[$idx], 'count'=>$count);
        }

        return $this->output;
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry but it's taking too much time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing to read the CSV file, but the fact the *values* of your name field contain special characters will not make a difference - they can still be used as keys in an associative array.  You should be doing something like this:

```
function readCsv($file,$indexName,$indexCount)
{
    $ret=array();
    $fh=fopen($file,"r");
    while (($data=fgetcsv($fh,1000))!==FALSE)
    {
        if (count($data)==1 && $data[0]===NULL)
            continue; // blank line
        $ar=array($data[$indexName]=>$data[$indexCount]);
        $ret[]=$ar;
    }
    fclose($fh);
    return $ret;
}

$file1_array=readCsv("file1.csv",0,1); // name in first column, count in second
$file2_array=readCsv("file2.csv",3,2); // name in 4th column, count in 3rd

$output=array();
foreach ($file1_array as $name=>$count)
{
    if (array_key_exists($name,$file2_array))
        $count=$file2_array[$name]/(1+$count);
    else $count=0;
    $output[]=array('name'=>$name,'count'=>$count);
}
```

Obviously, you will need to add error checking code, especially in the `readCsv()` function, but this should give you the results you are looking for.

Note that the `if ... else` can be rewritten as:

```
    $count=array_key_exists($name,$file2_array) ? $file2_array[$name]/(1+$count) : 0;
```

The following code should confirm to you that non-"regular" characters can be used for array key values:

```
$arr=array();
for ($cnt=1; $cnt<10; $cnt++)
    $arr[sprintf('ab1%c',$cnt+0x80)]=$cnt;
$str=sprintf('ab1%c',0x83);
for ($cnt=0; $cnt<4; $cnt++)
{
    $chr=$str[$cnt];
    echo '$str['.$cnt.'] = "'.$str[$cnt].'" = '.sprintf('0x%02x',ord($chr))."\n";
}
var_dump(str_split($str));
echo 'Valid key '.(array_key_exists($str,$arr) ? 'exists' : 'does not exist')."\n";
$str=sprintf('ab1%c',0x8f);
echo 'Invalid key '.(array_key_exists($str,$arr) ? 'exists' : 'does not exist')."\n";
```

which outputs:

```
$str[0] = "a" = 0x61
$str[1] = "b" = 0x62
$str[2] = "1" = 0x31
$str[3] = "?" = 0x83
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "?"
}
Valid key exists
Invalid key does not exist
```

Comment: items are not on the same position i need to find item of second file in first file. if i found one, i pick count for that otherwise use 0. But the way you have written it won't work in my situation.

Comment: Your question says "I loop through first file array and find the same element in file two array" which is what this code does.  If you need to find in the other direction, just change which one you open as file 1 and file 2.

Comment: I changed my answer to use zero if the name in file 1 isn't found in file 2.  I also changed the `readCsv()` function to support the name and count values being in arbitrary columns in the input files.

Comment: sorry, but i can't make $name element as array key because name contains special characters and different languages words.

Comment: You can't use special characters for the name of a variable, but $name is a string variable whose name is $name.  PHP strings are binary safe, so you _can_ use them as the keys in an index.  Have you actually tried it?